Magento 2 coding standards phpcs giving , ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.RemovedFunctions" does not exist
when I am running the command to check phpcs issues,
 vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 /filepath/


    ERROR: Referenced sniff "PHPCompatibility.FunctionUse.RemovedFunctions" does not exist
    Run "phpcs --help" for usage information

how to fix this?

To fix this issue add below code to composer.json file
 "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/,../../magento/php-compatibility-fork)"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/,../../magento/php-compatibility-fork)"
    ]
}

and run
composer update 

This will fix your issue
Thank you!

You can run below command to fix the issue,
composer require "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility:dev-develop" --with-all-dependencies

It will add all required dependencies and fix the error you are facing.
Let me know it this solution works!
